# Can I bulk purchase numbers from the Twilio API

Tags: twilio

I am trying to purchase mulitple numbers using c# with the Twilio API. However currently we must purchase one number at one time, It takes a lot of time to purchase 10-15 numbers in the loop.

So how can I pass a list of numbers through API so it takes less time to buy numbers from twilio.

Answer (score 5):

Twilio evangelist here.

Today there is no way to buy numbers in bulk via the API.  You have to make one [API request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers) per number that you want to buy.

If the library is not performing fast enough for you, first I'd love to know what kind of performance you are seeing and what you expect so I can work on improving the library.

Second, I'd suggest looking at just using the built in .NET HTTP client libraries instead of using the Twilio library.  The library is pretty general purpose and tuned more for ease of use than performance.  If you can use .NET 4 or higher, you can use the TPL to get some good perf gains.  I've built samples using the HttpClient library and TPL that resulting in substantially higher requests/sec than the library gives me today.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am working with the call tracking application where visitors purchases numbers from our website on bulk. I am using .net HTTP Client library to buy number from twilio but it takes too much time when visitors purchases 10, 12 numbers at once, here visitors can also buy maximum 99 numbers at once then it will take more time. Can you please tell me how can I make it easy.

Comment: I gave you some advice for ways to make it faster in my answer.  If you have specific questions about that advice I'm happy to help you out there.  I also would love to know exactly how long its taking per request.  That would be the most useful information to help you.